# mobile Spark list does not show the last registers

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

i have a list with 41 registers( i can see only 10 at once on the mobile screen) and when i scroll down with my finger, i can only reach to the register 38. I can see the other register if i move my finger slowly, but when i release the finger, the scroll sets its position again and the other register are not rendered( because they are 'outside' the screen)

It seems that the list 'thinks' that the last register for the scroll is the 38th register!!!

It's very strange...

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I was using a huge height value!